# How to return a DataRow in a StatefulWidget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi i'm making an app multiplatform, and i want display the data in a table in desktops, and in cards in mobile. I already have the view of the cards created with all the methods but when i try to returns a DataRow instead it gives me an error because DataRow is not a Widget. I want to make it in the same class so it can maintain the state. Is there any way or workaround to achieve this?

I expect something like this:

```
class MainView extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MainViewState();
}

class _MainViewState extends State<MainView> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isMobile ? Card( /* .... */ ) : DataRow( /* .... */ );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you don't want to display a single `Card` or `DataRow` in your app but rather a list of cards or a table consisting of several data rows. So create two methods that will turn the data you want to display into a list of `Card`s or `DataRow`s, then call the method that you need based on the platform, and wrap your resulting list in a `ListView` or `DataTable`. Both `ListView` and `DataTable` are widgets, so the `build` function of your `StatefulWidget` will no longer give you any errors.

Something like this:

```
List<Card> createCardList (data){...};
List<DataRow> createDataRowList(data){...};

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isMobile
       ? ListView(children: createCardList(dataFromBackEnd))
       : DataTable(
           columns: const <DataColumn>[...],
           rows: createDataRowList(dataFromBackEnd),
         );
}
```

Comment: Yes the problem is that i already have that structure and i would like to create a widget to work with every item, like is done already with the cards

Comment: @DavidEscariz If you insist on returning individual widgets in your build function, you could just use the `Row` widget instead of `DataRow`. Although the items in the various rows will most likely not be aligned vertically in that case.